# Conditional distribution of two binomials which both depend on a third

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have a question that I'm having some trouble with, but which I believe might have a fairly straightforward answer. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help point me in the right direction!

Let's say I have three binomial random variables, $C\sim\text{B}(N,c)$, and two which depend on it via $H\sim\text{B}(C,\gamma)$, and $N\sim\text{B}(C,\alpha)$, where $\gamma+\alpha\leq 1$.

What I'm looking for is the form of the conditional distribution $P(N\mid H)$. If it helps, I'm specifically interested in the case where $P(N\mid H=0)$.

Edit: I additionally require that $H+N\leq C$, which is the part that I'm not entirely sure how to deal with. If there's a better way to ask the question, I would really appreciate being corrected. I'm trying to model a process which occurs in two steps. In the first step, a number of events $C$ occur according to $C\sim B(N,c)$. Then in the second step, each one of those events can be classified either as $N$ or $H$, which is where the other two binomials came from. Perhaps this would be better modeled as a multinomial?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Elementary computations seem doable here. What did you try?

Comment: That's totally correct. Just realized I incorrectly stated the question. There's an additional constraint that $H+N\leq C$, which I believe complicates matters.

Comment: When you were only assuming that $H\sim\text{B}(C,\gamma)$ and $N\sim\text{B}(C,\alpha)$, one could complete the statement of the exercise assuming that $H$ and $N$ were conditionally independent conditionally on $C$. Now that you also require that $H+N\leq C$, this is not possible anymore. Actually the hypotheses $H\sim\text{B}(C,\gamma)$, $N\sim\text{B}(C,\alpha)$ and $H+N\leq C$ are not sufficient to solve the exercise, one must explain what is the conditional distribution of $(H,N)$ conditionally on $C$.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Sorry for the badly-formed question. Just edited!

Comment: Ach so... To sum up, you actually assume that $(H,N,C-H-N)$ is conditionally multinomial with parameters $C$ and $(\gamma,\alpha,1-\gamma-\alpha)$. Then at least the distribution of $N$ conditionally on $(C,H)$ is direct, no?

Comment: Ah, yes I believe that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!! My difficulty was in figuring out how best to formalize the process. That should do it!

Comment: You have $C\sim\text{B}(N,c)$ and $N\sim\text{B}(C,\alpha)$. Is that the same $N$ in both cases??